# Pyjnius import jar file

Tags: python, kivy, pyjnius

Pyjnius allows you to create a python wrapper for java classes like:

```
Hardware = autoclass('org.myapp.Hardware')
```

Is there a way to import an existing *.jar file like that? What does the syntax look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as `jar` file relevant only for android, you need to add jar file in your buildozer.spec like

```
android.add_jars = java/myjar.jar
```

and in your App's `build` method

```
from kivy.utils import platform
...
if platform() == 'android':
    BlaClass = autoclass('java.bla.BlaClass')
...
```

Comment: I just want to use some classes provided in some external jars in my python script. Is it not possible using jars which are not related to android?

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve. maybe jython would work for you

Answer (score 11):

You can add the jar into CLASSPATH, then import pyjnius and use autoclass as normal :-):

```
import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "path/to/your.jar"

from jnius import autoclass


Bla = autoclass('bla.bla.BlaClass')
```

Comment: What if i have more than 1 jar file , how i can include them ?

Comment: by separating them with `:` I would assume

Comment: A slightly cleaner equivalent would be `import jnius_config; jnius_config.set_classpath('/path/to/your.jar')`